# Come scrivere correttamente questa frase?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

1) Singolarmente Lei è insignificante, ma insieme agli altri come Lei costituisce quella massa che le élite manipolano psico-sociologicamente.

2) Singolarmente Lei è insignificante, ma insieme agli altri come Lei costituite quella massa che le élite manipolano psico-sociologicamente.

3) Singolarmente Lei è insignificante, ma insieme ad altri come Lei costituisce quella massa che le élite manipolano psico-sociologicamente.

4) Singolarmente Lei è insignificante, ma insieme ad altri come Lei costituite quella massa che le élite manipolano psico-sociologicamente.

Con riferimento al modo di accoppiare ad/agli con costituisce/costituite, le frasi di cui sopra sono corrette?

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 5):

Sono corrette la 1 e la 3.

“A insieme a B”, come soggetto, richiede il singolare (a differenza di “A e B”). E quindi – lasciando solo gli elementi essenziali – la forma corretta è “Lei ... insieme ad altri ... costituisce quella massa”.

Quanto alla scelta “agli altri/ad altri”, sono due possibilità con significati diversi. Come sempre, “gli altri” si riferisce a tutti gli altri di quella data categoria, mentre il semplice “altri” ad alcuni tra tanti.

Answer (score 1):

A, insieme a B, va allo zoo.

A e B insieme vanno allo zoo.

A è stanco, ma, insieme a B, va allo zoo.

A è stanco, ma insieme a B va allo zoo.  (accettabile)

* A è stanco, ma insieme a B vanno allo zoo. (non suona bene)

A è stanco, ma incontra B e insieme vanno allo zoo. (ok)

A, che è stanco, e B vanno allo zoo.